# How to read the transaction log for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, audit, transaction-log

I'd like to know whether there is any way of browsing/searching the SQL Server transaction logs (any version).
We've previously used tools such as Lumigent Log Explorer against SQL Server 2000 which fulfilled our need, but the product no longer exists and Lumigent's closest replacement doesn't appear to support SQL 2008 (according to the data sheet).

I've discovered something called ApexSQL Audit which may fit the bill, but I'm wondering if anyone has any experience of it, how it compares with Log Explorer, and whether there are any good alternatives out there.

Comment: If you don't need a tool, have a look here http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1443371/Viewing-the-Transaction-Log.htm

Comment: The question popped up again in the queue and was locked, I edited it a bit to see if it can be reopened as I think it might still be useful to update. If you disagree with my edits @martW, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [Apex SQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp). Apex SQL Audit builds auditing into a database. You can download Apex SQL Log for a free, full-featured trial.

Answer (score 1):

i believe Quest's Litespeed comes with a transaction log reader.

http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you need a [SQL log file viewer](http://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-log-analyzer.html) then you can go with SysTools SQL Log Analyzer. This is an excellent tool for analyzing transaction logs of a log file and also you can use this tool for forensics purposes.